# Simulate video dissemination with different bitrate on the network

Tags: video-streaming, wireless, omnet++, veins, bitrate

I use Veins to simulate video dissemination (omnetpp-4.6, sumo-0.25.0 and veins-4.4). I want to perform video dissemination with different bitrates. For which I use the traces from [this](http://trace.eas.asu.edu) website. All the video traces have fields such as: Sequence Number, Frame Type, Time [ms], Length.

In my network, one RSU broadcasts the  video sequence (~650MB) and  a vehicle downloads the video when it is within the RSU transmission range.

I need to simulate with different bitrate on the network. To change the bitrate, I edit this line in omnetpp.ini:

```
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.bitrate = 6Mbps
```

If the vehicle travel with a speed of 1m/s, it spends approx 1000 seconds within the RSU transmission range and the total downloaded file is 48.0607MB.
What could be the reasons for the size of the downloaded file to remain constant despite using different bitrates (3Mbps, 6Mbps, 9Mbps, 11Mbps, 18Mbps)?

Thanks in advance for your attention.